# Como subir imagenes con multer utilizando tokens?

Tags: nodejs, imagen, backend, tokens, multer

Estoy intentando subir un archivo de imagen utilizando Multer. Lo puedo hacer sin problemas al subirlas mediante un formulario que envíe datos através del actributo "action" y method="post" a rutas que no estan protegidas. Mi problema surge cuando quiero enviar el archivo a una ruta que necesita tokens para poder validar si el usuario es admin o no, ya que no puedo o no se como configurar un header personalizado a la peticion post que se genera en el formulario y asi incluir el token que se enviara al backend!

```
<form className='editProductContainer' action='http://localhost:4000/api/products/updateProduct' method='POST' encType='multipart/form-data'>
  <label className='labelContainer'>
        <p className='title'>ID: </p>
        <input type="text" name="id" value={inputID} placeholder={id} readOnly={true}/>
    </label>
    <label className='labelContainer'>
        <p className='title'>Nombre: </p>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={inputName} placeholder={name} onChange={(e:any) => setInputName(e.target.value)}/>
    </label>
    <label className='labelContainer'>
        <p className='title'>Precio: </p>
        <input type="number" name="price" value={inputPrice} placeholder={price.toString()} onChange={(e:any)=> setInputPrice(e.target.value)}/>
    </label>
    <label className='labelContainer' >
        <p className='title'>Imagen</p>
        <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*" onChange={(e:any)=> changeImg(e)} />
    </label> 
     <img className='productImg' src={loadImg}/>
    <div className='buttonWrapper'>
         <button className="buttonContainer" data-id={id} onClick={()=>goProducts()}>
              <p className= "title" data-id={id}>{'Cancelar'}</p>
          </button>
          <button className="buttonContainer" type='submit' data-id={id} >
              <p className= "title" data-id={id}>{'Guardar'}</p>
          </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**BACKEND**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,cb) => {
       cb(null, file= path.join(__dirname,'public/imgs'))
      },
       filename:(req,file,cb) => {
        cb(null,file.originalname);
        }
    });
  
  const upload = multer({storage: storage,
      fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpeg|gif|tif||tiff|heif|eps|ai|pdf|psd|webp|png|bmp|svg|jpg|avif)$/)) {
            return cb(new Error('Error en el tipo de archivo.'));
           }
        cb(null, true);
      }
    });
```

**ROUTER**

```
router.post("/updateProduct", upload.single('img'), async (req, res) => {
    await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.body.id,
        req.body, {
           new: true
        }
   )
   
   if(req.file){
       const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
       const changeImgProduct = await Product.findById(req.body.id);
       changeImgProduct.imgURL = result.secure_url;
       await changeImgProduct.save();
       await fs.unlink(req.file.path);
     }
     
     res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/products');
   });
```

Comment: Tenés algo de código para compartir? Así podemos guiarnos mejor sobre lo que necesitás

Comment: Depende de como estes leyendo el token. Puedes poner que estás usando para auntenticar al usuario? Generalmente el token se usa con la cabezera "Bearer aqui-tu-token" y en el backend se lee esta cabecera para saber si tiene permisos.

Comment: Al token lo genero con Jwt y lo mando del frontend al backend en el header como "x-access-token", esto lo puedo hacer al usar fetch, ya que permite personalizar los headers, pero no se como hacerlo con los formularios! No se si hay otra manera de subir archivos, con multer es la que aprendi y me resulto facil hasta que me tope con esto de verificar !